# Xbox One controller on Windows 10 not working properly

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, windows-10

When I use my Xbox One controllers on my windows 10 computer, sometimes the keys stick(not physically stuck, but my guy runs forward when im not pressing forward) sometimes I press a key and it does nothing.

Comment: Did you check the controller was compatible with your game? What game? Might want more detail and clarify it.

Comment: I would also like to know more about this problem. It seems random to me. Sometimes I'll load a game and my controller seems to have a zero-dead-zone and only some buttons work. Restarting my games has worked so far and the problem is not specific to any game.

Answer (score 1):

You can try resetting the configuration of the controller in Windows

- Open Run (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
- Type `joy.cpl` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- On the Game Controllers Window, click 'Properties' (Button)
- Go to the Settings tab
- Click 'Reset To Default' (Button)

This solved my problem for now. If I continue to have problems, I will be back.

On the Test Tab of that window. I was able to see that my left analog stick was acting strange. It was locking to only the corners of the box and not traveling anywhere in between.